# MonoDevelop Custom Syntax Highlighting

Tags: syntax, monodevelop, highlighting

I'm trying to setup an custom syntax highlighting scheme for MonoDevelop. The problem is that i can't seem to add an new one using the add button it always gives me errors. The weird thing is that even the ones that are provided with MonoDevelop (downloaded from github) don't work via de add button. I found some examples on the net, but they also give errors.

Does anybody have any clue whats wrong, or what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your Time,
Richard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on this page on the [MonoDevelop Site](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Syntax_Mode_Definition) there some explanation of how to add the syntax files. 
(the xml ones)